# Querying a MongoDB with $all on an empty array doesn't return results

Tags: mongodb

When I query my MongoDB server with a filter using $all and an empty array I don't get any results.

I am using pymongo and when my query looks like this:

```
my_collection.find({"some_field": some_value, "array_field": {"$all": []}})
```

I don't get any result. If I change it to this:

```
my_collection.find({"some_field": some_value})
```

I do get the results I want.

Is this behavior as should be (and I should not send an $all filter if the array is empty)?

My reference is 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`$all` is used to query a list and will match when all items in your specified list match with items in the database list; you have no items in the all query, so the query makes no sense; I'm surprised it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: That is quite bad client experience as I would expect that an empty array would be a subset of every array.